# Unable to launch the IIS Express Web Server in visual studio 2017. Output says IIS Express is running but not

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-10, webserver

In visual studio 2017, suddenly I started facing below issue, don't know the reason.
[image]

Comment: firewall was creating problem, i stopped the firewall and it started working.